# Slick - Filter Row if Column is Null

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

How do I filter rows in Slick if a column is null?

```
val employees = Queryable[Employees]

// Error
val query = employees.filter( _.terminationDate == Nil )
```

Might be important to note that

```
terminationDate: Option[String]
```

I am using Direct Embedding.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Newer versions of Slick:

```
val query = employees.filter(_.terminationDate.isEmpty)
```

and

```
val query = employees.filter(_.terminationDate.isDefined)
```

Older versions of Slick had their own way of checking for null values in a column:

```
val query = employees.filter(_.terminationDate.isNull)
```

The opposite was `isNotNull`.

Comment: I thought it would be something like that, but using your code I get: `Type mismatch.  Expected (Employees) => Boolean, actual (Employees) => Any`

Comment: I can't reproduce your error to be honest, also that error doesn't seem slick related.

Comment: I am using direct embedding.  Maybe that is why.

Comment: I get errors using your code with the regular lifted embedding.  Are you also on version 2?

Comment: Yes I'm on version 2.X but I've never use the direct embedding feature.

Comment: It seems at least in slick 3.1.1 `isEmpty` and `isDefined` no longer exist. The only way I can find to do a null check is something like: `.filter(_.terminationDate === Option.empty[String])`

Comment: @CharlieBrown it should still work on - as long as your column is defined as a `column[Option[SomeType]]` rather than a `column[SomeType]`. I think `isEmpty` and `isDefined` are only defined on columns of type `Rep[Option[_]]`

Comment: "newer versions of Slick" = 2.1.0, http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/2.1.0/upgrade.html#isnull-and-isnotnull